# How to resolve shadow importing issue?

Tags: package, common-lisp, sbcl

I have a function I created called `ENCODE-JSON-TO-STRING` in my package called `libray`.

I wanted to replace my function with the function from `cl-json`. Which is also called `ENCODE-JSON-TO-STRING`.

I removed my function with `fmakunbound`.

However when I try to import cl-json I get the following error:

```lisp
 LIBRARY also shadows the following symbols:
      (JSON:ENCODE-JSON-TO-STRING)

compilation failed
```

My goal is to completely erase the existance of `LIBRARY:ENCODE-JSON-TO-STRING`

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package importing looks on symbols, and does not care whether they are bound or fbound or not.

The term to remove symbol from package is unintern, and the function to achieve it has same name - [unintern](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_uninte.htm), so what you look for should be `(unintern 'LIBRARY:ENCODE-JSON-TO-STRING 'library)`.

You may also want to have a look on `shadowing-import` and [package concepts](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/11_a.htm) in general.

Of course, simplest way may be just simply restart and rebuild your system from clean image without creating `LIBRARY:ENCODE-JSON-TO-STRING` at all.

Comment: How does one `restart and rebuild your system from clean image`?

Comment: What I meant was to start clean empty instance of the implementation (sbcl, lispworks or whatever) and load the necessary libraries from the files/asdf systems/however it was done originally. This assumes you have the sources, and that the offending symbol is no longer created by them.